# Angular view gets out of sync with model when dragging items from one list to another

Tags: jquery-ui, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created a custom directive that allows me to connect multiple sortable lists via drag and drop using angular js and jquery ui. The way it should work is the following:

1. When drag starts, keep track of the initial position of the item in the array and the value of ng-model for that sortable
2. When the drag ends, if the item is received to a different list, keep track of the ng-model of that list and the target position of the element
3. Broadcast an event with that data so that the controller can change the positions of the items from one array to another

The problem is that once I move one item from one list to another, even though the items in the arrays go where they should, in the view some HTML elements disappear.

Here is the sortable directive:

```
app.directive('mySortable',function(){
return {    
link:function(scope,el,attrs){
  var options = {};

  if(attrs.connectWith)
  {
    options.connectWith = attrs.connectWith;
  }

  el.sortable(options);
  el.disableSelection();

  el.on("sortstart", function(event, ui){
    var from_index = angular.element(ui.item).scope()?angular.element(ui.item).scope().$index : 0;
    var from_model = angular.element(ui.item.parent()).attr('ng-model');    
    ui.item.scope().sortableData = {from_index: from_index, from_model: from_model};
  });


  el.on("sortreceive", function(event, ui){
    ui.item.scope().sortableData.to_index = el.children().index(ui.item);
    ui.item.scope().sortableData.to_model = angular.element(el).attr('ng-model');        
  });


  el.on( "sortdeactivate", function( event, ui ) {        

    var to_model = angular.element(el).attr('ng-model');                        
    var from = angular.element(ui.item).scope()?angular.element(ui.item).scope().$index : 0;
    var to = el.children().index(ui.item);


    if(to>=0){
      scope.$apply(function(){            
        if(from>=0){
          scope.$emit('list-sorted', {from:from,to:to}, ui.item.scope());
        }else{              
          scope.$emit('list-appended', {to:to, name:ui.item.text()});
          ui.item.remove();
        }
      })          
    }        

  } );
}
}
 })
```

And here is the controller logic that handles it's event:

```
$scope.$on('list-sorted', function(ev, val, task_scope){            
    var sd = task_scope.sortableData;   

    if(sd.to_model)
    {   
        $timeout(function(){
            $scope[sd.to_model].splice(sd.to_index, 0, $scope[sd.from_model].splice(sd.from_index, 1)[0]);
        });         
    }
    else
    {   
        $timeout(function(){
            $scope[sd.from_model].splice(val.to, 0, $scope[sd.from_model].splice(val.from, 1)[0]);                  
        });     
    }
    console.log($scope);        
});
```

What's wrong?

**[Example JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/loupax/EL4H8/)**

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the controller logic comports an error.

Is it fine like this:

```
var sd = item_scope.sortableData;       
    // If the item is supposed to be dropped to a different list, move it from one list to another
    if(sd.to_model)
    {   
        console.log("to a different list", val)
        $timeout(function(){    
            $scope[sd.to_model].splice(val.to, 0, $scope[sd.from_model].splice(sd.from_index, 0));               
        });         
    }
    else
    {   
        console.log("to the same list")
        $timeout(function(){
            $scope[sd.from_model].splice(val.to, 0, $scope[sd.from_model].splice(val.from, 1)[0]);                  
        });     
    }
```

Comment: The DOM might be correct that way, but the contents of the arrays stay the same, so the view and the model are still out of sync